# Отображение фона в safari

Tags: safari, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему фон [странички](http://prozaik.16mb.com/html5/q1/) отображается во всех браузерах кроме `safari 5.1`?

На [этой страничке](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/joomla_42334/) фон сделан аналогично, но он отображается в `safari`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего потому, что safari не поддерживает такую запись:

```
background: url("../images/bg_wrap0.jpg") no-repeat fixed center center / cover transparent;
```

и Вам следует записать её иначе:

```
background: url(../images/bg_wrap0.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: спасибо. всё именно так

Answer (score 2):

Хватит и двух строчек). У меня сработало в `Safari 5.1.7`:

```
background: url(../img/shadow.png) 50% -0.6rem no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
```